How to make the code snippet contains anonymous namespace defined in class work?
How to make the code snippet below work?
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    namespace { // Anonymous namespace declaration
        void internalFunction() {
            std::cout << "Internal function called" << std::endl;
        }
    };
public:
    MyClass() {
        // Access anonymous entities
        internalFunction();
    }

    void doSomething() {
        // Access anonymous entities
        internalFunction();
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass obj;
    obj.doSomething();
    return 0;
}

What I want to do?
I have some plain functions which would only be merely useful for a class. So, I think they should not be defined outside the said class. And since they are plain functions, I think namespace is better than class.

what made you believe you can introduce a namespace inside a class definition? or what would it be good for?

are you looking for private ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I have some plain functions which would only be merely useful for a class. I think it should not defined outside the said class. And since they are plain functions, I think namespace is better than class.

The question makes no sense, and it's most probably because you misunderstood what namespaces (anonymous or not) do.

the only way to have it "not be defined outside the said class" is to define it inside the class. You could use a friend function that is not declared outside of the class, though ADL would make it sill accessible from outside the class. I think you are really looking for private.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

If you want a piece of code that is used only by the class but makes no use of class object, there are two usual solutions.

private static functions, the default solution:

class MyClass {
private:
    //inaccessible to outsiders but still visible in the header
    static void internalFunction() {
        std::cout << "Internal function called" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    MyClass() {
        // use the implementation detail nobody outside has to know about
        internalFunction();
    }

    void doSomething() {
        // use the implementation detail nobody outside has to know about
        internalFunction();
    }
};


A function in anonymous namespace in the implementation file. Useful if the function has some type in its signature you don't want to expose:

//in my_class.h
class MyClass {
private:
    //dear clients, nothing to see here    
public:
    MyClass();

    void doSomething();
};

//in my_class.cpp
#include "my_class.h"

namespace {
void internalFunction() {
    std::cout << "Internal function called" << std::endl;
}
}//namespace <local> (useful to mark closing namespace bracket with a comment)

MyClass::MyClass() {
    // use the implementation detail nobody outside has to know about
    internalFunction();
}

void MyClass::doSomething() {
    // use the implementation detail nobody outside has to know about
    internalFunction();
}

Notice that using anonymous namespaces in header files (where class declarations usually go) would be a horrible idea even if it worked: it would create a copy of your internalFunction() in every compilation unit. Which is not only ineffective but can break your code if, say, internalFunction() uses static variables.

private static member functions could not be accessed outside the class?

@John Yes. Accessing any name declared the private section from anywhere but that class' methods (or methods of its nested classes ± some edge cases) is a compilation error.
